# Select not matched record from two collection using linq

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I have 2 collection col1 and col2. i want select record from col1 are not matched in col2. in col1 have 0 to 6 and in col2 have 1 to 6 number , i want 0 because 0 is not matched in col2 .

Both collection have not same type, have a field ID in both collection.

I am using c# 4.0(Linq).

Comment: Can i know any reason why negative marking??????

Comment: You haven't show any effort of completing this task by yourself, you haven't provide code which shows your problem, and your question initially missed most important part - that collections are not simple numbers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need the [`Except`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb300779.aspx) method:

```
var yourResult = col1.Except(col2);
```

If both of your collections aren't the same type, then you're going to have to do a more expensive `O(nm)` search:

```
var selectedTwo = col2.Select(x => x.ID).ToHashSet();
var yourResult = col1.Where(n => !selectedTwo.Contains(n.ID));
```

And somewhere else in your code:

```
public static HashSet<T> ToHashSet<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source)
{
    return new HashSet<T>(source);
}
```

Comment: Actually my both collection are not same. so Except will not work. any alternate please.

Comment: @JasRajBishnoi Yes, a more expensive O(nm) search instead of the (best case, and usual case) O(n+m) granted by Except.

Comment: This is working proper if having not matched only one record , if 2 or 3 record not matching then returning nothing. any solution please

Answer (score 1):

For different collection you can try this

```
var outputarray = 
                  FirstList.Except(
                  (from first in FirstList
                  join second in SecondList
                  on first.id equals second.id
                  select first).ToList());
```

Answer (score 0):

assuming the type of ur `collection` is `string` thn

```
var resultCol = new List<string>();

col1.ToList().ForEach(item => {
    if(!col2.Contains(item))
        resultCol.Add(item);
});
```

Comment: @JasRaj Bishnoi : u shd mention it in ur question

Comment: @newStackExchangeInstance wat type of error, show me any (exclude 1st line, bcoz i dont know the type of that collection)

Comment: 1) You can't var a variable you don't inline declare. 2) It's ToList. 3) It's ForEach. 4) It's Contains. 5) It's Add.

Comment: @newStackExchangeInstance i dont think somebody'll jst copy it & paste  expecting to execute without any error, these r self understood things (toList -> ToList etc), moreover the 1st line i already said i dont know the type (if that `string` than that whd b `new List<string>`)

Comment: For **E** ach and also he wants to do it by the ID column.